# ms access before change macro not working

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to use Microsoft Access data macro:

`IF [Dataset_Used]='VS' And IsNull([VS_File]) Then`

RaiseError

```
  Error Number:  4002
  Error Description: Please choose a VS file
```

Above macro is working. But if I add `And [Note]<>'no file'` to the If condition
`[Dataset_Used]='VS' And IsNull([VS_File]) And [Note]<>'no file'`,
the macro will not work.  Working means the error description will be displayed when If condition is met.

Comment: The [Dataset_used] is a column with value 'VS', 'HDDS', etc, When the  value is 'VS' and file is available, user will choose a VS file for the VS_File column.  if no file is available, the user will put the 'no file' in the table [Note] column.  So if there is 'no file' in the [Note] and  [Dataset_used] with value 'VS', the user should choose a VS file; otherwise it will display the error description.

Comment: Did you confirm there are records meeting these criteria? Apply these as filter directly in query to test. Any records returned?

Comment: The situation is like this:  The table. among others, has columns: [Dataset_used], [VS_File], [Note].  [Dataset_used] has values like 'VS', 'HDDS'.   Other two are blanks.   if there are files available, and [Dataset_used] is VS, so choose one of the VS file for [VS_File], if not available, put 'no file' in the [Note].   the before change data macro is to remind the user to choose a VS file or put 'no file'.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. How does code know files are available? All your code does is check if a field has been populated. And if Note is blank, why are you looking for a match to 'no file'? This field is either Null or string 'no file'? I don't use macros, only VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this condition:

```
And Nz([Note])<>'no file'
```

Quite sure `[Note]` field contains mostly Nulls. Null is a special case, `Null <> "something"` equals Null, not True or False. `True And Null` gives also Null. But `True Or Null` gives True.